# Test for np.nan in row wise function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a function that I want to apply to each row of a data frame to create a new column. The value returned from the function will be different if certain columns are NaN. I have several conditions in the function (more complicated than the example below), otherwise, I would use `np.where`.

How do I test if the column is nan using the function below? I tried `row['id'] is np.nan` but that doesn't work.

```
# data
d = {'name': {0: 'dave', 1: 'hagen'},
     'id': {0: 123456.0, 1: np.nan},
     'position': {0: np.nan, 1: 5600.0},
     'test': {0: 'has an id', 1: 'has an id'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# function
def test_func(row):
    if row['id'] is np.nan:
        val = "missing id"
    else:
        val = 'has an id'
    return val

# apply function
df['test'] = df.apply(test_func, axis=1)
```

Results (I would expect the `test` column to say "missing an id" on the second row since id is `np.nan` on that row:

[image]

Comment: numpy has its own isnan() function:

val = "missing id" if np.isnan(row['id']) else 'has an id'

Comment: Alternatively, you could `pandas.isnull()` like: `if pd.isnull(row.at["id"])`

Comment: @Glauco - your solution worked with my function. Do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

numpy has its own [isnan() function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html#numpy-isnan):

the simplest way is:

```
val = "missing id" if np.isnan(row['id']) else 'has an id'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.where`:

```
>>> df
    name        id  position
0   dave  123456.0       NaN
1  hagen       NaN    5600.0
```

```
df['test'] = np.where(df['id'].isna(), 'missing id', 'has an id')
```

```
>>> df
    name        id  position        test
0   dave  123456.0       NaN   has an id
1  hagen       NaN    5600.0  missing id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`numpy.isnan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) and replace booleans with your custom string using [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df['test'] = df['id'].isna().replace({True: 'missing id', False: 'has an id'})
```

output:

```
    name        id  position        test
0   dave  123456.0       NaN   has an id
1  hagen       NaN    5600.0  missing id
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for something this simple is usually code smell. You can use the [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) method to do the same thing in one line:

```
df.loc[df['id'].isna(), 'test'] = 'missing id'
```

The problem with [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) is that there are [multiple representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Encoding) of it, so `is` is not guaranteed to work by any means, and it's specifically defined so that [`Nan != Nan`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Comparison_with_NaN).

Given that all you are looking for is the mask `df['id'].isna()`, you may not need an explicit `test` column at all. That applies to more complicated conditions as well. You can combine masks using `&` and `|` element-wise bit operators. For example, to include a condition on either of the columns:

```
df.loc[df['id'].isna() | df['position'].isna(), 'test'] = 'missing id'
```

Alternatively, you can do

```
df.loc[df[['id', 'position']].isna().any(axis=1), 'test'] = 'missing id'
```